# ipsec routing / strange routing behavior

Tags: linux, vpn, iptables, routing, ipsec

I have following network configuration:

```
Office1 <-- openvpn --> office2 <-- ipsec tunnel --> branch office
```

Office1 and office2 are on Debian, Branch office: juniper srx100

```
Office1 network: 172.17.20.0/24
Office2 network: 192.168.31.0/24
Branch network: 192.168.16.0/24
```

What works: office1 <-> office2, branch_office <-> office2, branch office --> office1

but traffic from office1 can't reach branch office from office1.
Traffic comes to office2 and disappears.
Nothing logged by "-j LOG" iptables rules

Why it doesn't work? How it can be fixed?

**upd:**

->> *Can you show the routing tables from all 3 devices?* – Tom O'Connor♦ 3 hours ago
1

Office1:

```
192.168.31.0/24 via 192.168.31.254 dev tun6
192.168.16.0/24 via 192.168.31.254 dev tun6 
172.17.20.0/24 dev vlan20  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.17.20.1 
default via 85.21.118.145 dev vlan7
```

office2:

```
172.17.20.1 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.31.254 
192.168.70.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.70.254 
192.168.31.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.31.254 
172.17.20.0/24 via 172.17.20.1 dev tun0 
default via 62.176.6.1 dev eth1
```

branch office:

```
show route 

inet.0: 8 destinations, 8 routes (8 active, 0 holddown, 0 hidden)
+ = Active Route, - = Last Active, * = Both

0.0.0.0/0          *[Static/5] 1w0d 04:16:31
                    > to 109.195.11.254 via fe-0/0/0.0
109.195.10.0/23    *[Direct/0] 1w0d 04:16:31
                    > via fe-0/0/0.0
109.195.10.17/32   *[Local/0] 1w0d 04:16:31
                      Local via fe-0/0/0.0
172.17.20.0/24     *[Static/5] 00:37:33
                    > via st0.0
192.168.16.0/24    *[Direct/0] 6d 04:54:35
                    > via vlan.0
192.168.16.1/32    *[Local/0] 1w0d 04:32:01
                      Local via vlan.0
192.168.31.0/24    *[Static/5] 00:37:33
                    > via st0.0
192.168.70.0/24    *[Static/5] 00:37:33
                    > via st0.0
```

-> *How do the IPsec policies look like between office2 and branch office? (try ip xfrm policy on office2)*

```
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
        dir 4 priority 0 ptype main 
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
        dir 3 priority 0 ptype main 
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
        dir 4 priority 0 ptype main 
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
        dir 3 priority 0 ptype main 
src 192.168.16.0/24 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
        dir fwd priority 2147483648 ptype main 
        tmpl src branch_ip dst office2_ip
                proto esp reqid 0 mode tunnel
src 192.168.16.0/24 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
        dir in priority 2147483648 ptype main 
        tmpl src branch_ip dst office2_ip
                proto esp reqid 0 mode tunnel
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 192.168.16.0/24 
        dir out priority 2147483648 ptype main 
        tmpl src office2_ip dst branch_ip
                proto esp reqid 0 mode tunnel
```

Comment: Can you show the routing tables from all 3 devices?

Comment: How do the IPsec policies look like between _office2_ and _branch office_? (try `ip xfrm policy` on _office2_)

Answer (score 0):

You might not have enabled IP forwarding on office2.  Try either:

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

or Debian specifically:

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
```

The parameter should be "1".  On Debian, edit /etc/sysctl.conf and somewhere (around lines 27 and 28 on Squeeze) you should find -

```
# Uncomment the next line to enable packet forwarding for IPv4
#net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Uncomment the line, reboot, and you should find it's now persistently set to forward packets.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but it has been done long ago (even before branch office has been created).